# Installing and using Cordova plugin in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, git, visual-studio, cordova, plugins

I have a cross platform app built using OnsenUI, Monaca and Cordova and Im using Visual Studio as my IDE.

I have Monaca configured in Visual Studio using [THIS](https://docs.monaca.io/en/manual/development/monaca_vs/) guide and it is working 100%.

I need my app to run in the background even when the app is closed etc. and for this I have installed [THIS](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) plugin via Visual Studio to achieve the task.

Ti install the plugin, in Visual Studio I select the config.xml file of my project then choose -> Plugins -> Custom -> Git and enter the URL of the plugin as above. Visual Studio install the plugin and I get a success message. I check the folder structure of my project and in the *plugins* folder I see the installed plugin.

I have installed other plugins in a similar fashion before e.g. Camera and it has worked as intended.

I then try to use the plugins functions as per the usage guide [HERE](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode#usage) but I keep getting the error ***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundMode' of undefined"***

I have also tried to call the function as below as per some suggestions but I still get the same error.

```
window.cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text: 'Doing heavy tasks.' });
```

I try calling the function in a *controller* as below (abbreviated sample)

```
var mainNavigation = angular.module("mainNavigationController", []);
mainNavigation.controller("MainNavigationController", function ($scope, NetworkConnection) {
    var init = function () {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    };

    init();

    function onDeviceReady() {
        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text: 'Doing heavy tasks.' }); // Not working
        window.cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text: 'Doing heavy tasks.' }); // Not working either
    };
});
```

I have also tried adding the sample code to my projects loader.js file as below (abbreviated version), but again I get the same error.

```
// This is an auto-generated code by Monaca JS/CSS Components. Please do not edit by hand.
/*** <Start:monaca-cordova-loader> ***/
/*** <Start:monaca-cordova-loader LoadJs:"components/monaca-cordova-loader/cordova-loader.js"> ***/
(function(){
  function getDeviceObjectForPreview() {
    // Code omitted
  }

/*** <Start:monaca-core-utils> ***/
/*** <Start:monaca-core-utils LoadJs:"components/monaca-core-utils/monaca-core-utils.js"> ***/
/*** Monaca Core Utility Library. This library requires cordova.js ***/
window.monaca = window.monaca || {};
(function() {
    // Code omitted

    monaca.isDeviceReady = monaca.isDeviceReady || false;
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){
        window.monaca.isDeviceReady = true;
        monaca.apiQueue.next();

        cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text: 'Doing heavy tasks.' }); // Not working
    }, false);
}
```

I have not imported any files in my index.html file e.g.

```
<script src="js/canvasDraw/signatureCapture.js"></script>
```

Why am I getting the undefined error? I have checked and cordova.js is loaded from loader.js as well.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you use [device emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) but not just browser-based emulator like Ripple-Nexus.

In browser plugins will not work correctly. This mode is good just for debugging your JS application and some common API.

In documentation of [Ripple Simulator](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/) you can find:

> Caution: Ripple doesn’t provide a complete simulation of Cordova APIs or native device capabilities (plugins). It also doesn’t simulate specific browser versions for a particular platform. You can achieve this by testing on actual devices or emulators.